# Use position of character in a string to remove part of a string in a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I Have a dataframe with a column that contains strings which have an '_' followed a different number of characters in each row:

e.g.

```
"LOCATION_B A PP E1"
"POSITION_P&A F A M"
```

I want to remove the underscore and everything to the right of it.

If I knew the number of characters, n, this would work:

```
df[0] = df[0].str[:n]
```

So to do this for the DataFrame I'm using the following to find the position of the right most underscore and remove it and everything after it:

```
df[0] = df[0].str[:(df[0].str.rfind('_'))]
```

This returns NaN. Any ideas as to why this is happening or how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df[0] = df[0].str.split('_').str[0]
```

Or:

```
df[0] = df[0].str.partition('_')[0]
```

Comment: wiki time again?

Comment: Thanks! I've modified this slightly to remove the rightmost underscore and everything to the right of it: `df[0] = df[0].str.split('_').str[:-1].str.join("_")`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
df[0] = df[0].apply(lambda x : x.split('_')[0])
```

Comment: I'm getting an attribute error here: AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: @brendan1229 are df[0] values string or float?